# Laplacian and Hodge Laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, sobolev-spaces

I am new to the theory of differential forms, but there is one thing that I don't get at all. Imagine that you are on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$, then the Laplacian $- \Delta$ is known to be a continuous operator $L(W^k_2,W^{k-2}_2),$ where $W$ is the appropriate Sobolev space.

Now, I found that there is also the concept of a De Rham Laplacian for manifolds, as you can see here for example [on wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator#Laplace.E2.80.93de_Rham_operator)

At this point, I read now that this one maps $k-$forms to $k-$forms. So how is this operator different from the Laplacian that I defined in the first place?- I thought that this definition is  a generalization of the Laplacian, but I can't see how these $k-$forms are now related to the Sobolev space.

So is this Hodge Laplacian something completely different or is this one related to my operator defined in the first paragraph?

Comment: Is $W^k_2$ the space of $k$-times differentiable functions in $L^2(S^2)$?

Comment: I take it the Laplacian you talk about in the beginning is defined for real or complex valued functions, but you can define a Sobolev space of $p$-forms, and more generally, Sobolev spaces of sections of vector bundles.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang yes indeed

Comment: @OlivierBégassat could you give me a hint, how my Sobolev space os related to a Sobolev space of forms?

Comment: The Sobolev space of functions is just the Sobolev space of sections of the trivial line bundle.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat would you mind making this precise in an answer, i.e. the question: From where to where does the Hodge Laplacian map and why is this the same(or not) as the first definition?

Answer (score 8):

The first Laplacian you mention (sometimes called the Laplace-Beltrami operator) acts on scalar functions, that is, functions $S^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. The de Rham (a.k.a. Hodge) Laplacian acts on differential forms. In particular, the de Rham Laplacian acts on zero-forms, which are precisely scalar functions $S^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, on which it agrees with the Laplace-Beltrami operator. That is the sense in which the latter Laplacian is a generalization of the former.

One can also study Sobolev spaces of differential forms (or of sections of more general vector bundles), and a statement similar to what you said holds for more general Laplace operators. And of course, all of these things can be studied on Riemannian manifolds other than $S^2$.

But before one learns about Sobolev spaces of differential forms, it is important to understand the basic theory of smooth ($C^\infty$) differential forms (i.e., the usual things that people refer to as differential forms). Then one can start thinking about Laplace operators, etc. The most natural way to view the de Rham Laplacian (or any differential operator on forms, at least at first) is as an operator that maps smooth differential forms to smooth differential forms. After you understand that, you can think about its properties with respect to Sobolev spaces.

One good source for this is Rosenberg's book *The Laplacian on a Riemannian Manifold*, which is available as a pdf on his website.

Comment: could you try to explain in what way such a form generalizes an ordinary let's say $L^2$ function?

Comment: or more explicitely: I would be interested in the question: How my Sobolev space is related to the Sobolev space of forms?

Comment: As I said, you should understand smooth forms and smooth functions before thinking about Sobolev spaces. Differential forms are (locally, at least) essentially vector-valued functions, i.e., functions with multiple components. For example, on an $n$-manifold, one-forms are specified locally by $n$ functions. (In loose terms, I think one can say that a one-form is in, say, $L^2$ essentially when each of those $n$ functions are in $L^2$. But this should be made more precise.) You should start by reading a source like Rosenberg, or better yet, a more elementary book on differential forms.

Comment: @Juschka differential forms are not functions.  They are a more natural version of what might be called a *vector field* on the sphere.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang what do you mean by more natural? Actually, I think that the domain I have written down above there is most natural, as the Laplacian is self-adjoint there on the domain $W^2(\mathbb{S}^2)$. This is why I thought that any reasonable extension of a suitable domain on manifolds should contain this somehow.

Comment: @PhillipAndreae the thing is that I was wondering if this concept of forms somehow contains and simplifies the problem of studying operators on manifolds, which is why I got interested in this subject, but apparently this seems to be not the case, as forms seem to be "something else".

Comment: @Juschka: "natural" in the mathematical sense means *without reference to additional structure*.  In calculus the curl is a kind of differential operator that takes vector fields to vector fields, but it requires a metric.  Whereas the differential of a one-form is a two-form, and no metric is needed to define it.  Like Philip said, you'll need to read a book because it's hard to explain in comment threads. :-)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I am not sure, that you got my question, right. I would really like to read on this on my own, but I have some applications in mind. The application requires that it is possible to construct the Laplacian that I wrote down there by differential forms (on the same domain). If this is possible, then this would be great and I would really love to read about it, but if this whole formalism does not cover this, then I think I can leave it there. If I understood you correctly, then the latter is the case, i.e. the de Rham Laplacian is different from the Laplacian as this operator.

Comment: @Juschka: Could the following be what you mean? The Laplace-Beltrami operator applied to a function $f$ may be expressed as $d^\ast (df)$. $d$ is the exterior derivative mapping functions to one-forms, and $d^\ast$ is its adjoint. This is one way to express the Laplacian on functions that involves using differential forms (although there are other ways to express it that don't mention differential forms).

Comment: I like your clear explanation! If any of you guys could help out with my question, that'll be great too :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754019/fundamental-solution-of-the-four-dimensional-laplacian