# Fundamental Solution of the Four-Dimensional Laplacian

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

I wish to show that the fundamental solution of the four-dimensional laplacian $∆u = u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz} + u_{ww}$ is $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2}$ Is there a way to do this via direct computation according to its definition?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** By spherical coordinates, the Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^4$ can
be written as
\begin{align}
\Delta_{\mathbb{R}^4}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{3}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\Delta_{S^{3}}
\end{align}
where $\Delta_{S^3}$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $S^3$, which is not important in our case.

Find all solution to the radial part, i.e. solve the ODE
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r^3}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r^3\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right)=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2}+\frac{3}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=0.
\end{align}

Comment: I haven't seen such a complicated ODE though. How to solve :/

Comment: @Homaniac Set $u' = v$ to make the ODE first order, then use an integrating factor.

Comment: I get $u=r^4/4$ but how does that lead to the final answer?

Comment: @Homaniac You integrated incorrectly then \begin{align} u'' + \frac{3}{r}u' &= 0 \\ \implies r^{3}u'' + 3r^{2}u' &= 0 \\ \implies (r^{3}u')' &= 0 \\ \implies u' &= \frac{C_{1}}{r^{3}} \\ \implies u &= \frac{-C_{1}}{2r^{2}} + C_{2} \end{align}